# Independence of a random variable and its conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathcal{P})$ be a probability space.

Let $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{F}$ be a sub $\sigma$-algebra, and let $X\in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathcal{P})$ be a random variable.

Suppose that $\mathcal{H}$ is independent of $\sigma(\sigma(X),\mathcal{G})$.

Then, I want to show that

(1) $I_{H}$ and $I_{G}X$ are independent.

(2) $I_{H}$ and $I_{G}E[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$

where $H \in \mathcal{H}, G \in \mathcal{G}$ and $E[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$ denotes the conditional expectatinon $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$.

For (1), I know that $\sigma(I_{H}) = \{\Omega,\emptyset,H,H^c\}$, but I do not know what $\sigma(I_{G}X)$. Similarily, I could not characterize what $\sigma(I_{G}E[X \mid \mathcal{G}])$ other than saying that $\sigma(I_{G}E[X \mid \mathcal{G}]) = \{ (I_{G}E[X \mid \mathcal{G}])^{-1}(B), \text{ where B is Borel}   \}$.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Both $1_G X$ and $1_G \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})$ are measurable with respect to $\sigma(\sigma(X),\mathcal{G})$.
2. Since $\mathcal{H}$ and $\sigma(\sigma(X),\mathcal{G})$ are, by assumption, independent, it follows from the first step that $1_H$ and $1_G X$ as well as $1_H$ and $1_G \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})$ are independent.

Comment: I got it thx to your hints :)